# I get this error whenever I try installing Firebase CLI using Powershell

Tags: node.js, npm

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g firebase-tools

npm : npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
At line:1 char:1

- npm install -g firebase-tools
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm WARN deprec...est/issues/3142:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
  ```

npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://npm.community
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MANS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-02-11T11_40_21_018Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

By running the following commands in your terminal, your issue should be resolved.

1. `npm cache clean`
2. `npm install -g npm`
3. `npm install`
4. `expo install firebase`